# Symfony 2.8 UserController password of User Entity

Tags: symfony

I'm very new to Symfony 2. I have a method that brings all the user data to my front-end app. But I don't want to bring every property of the User entity. This is the code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
$id  = $user->getId();
$rol = $user->getUserRoles()->getId();
$orgId = $user->getUserOrganizaciones()->getId();
switch($rol){
    case 1:
        $entities = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                        ->select('User')
                        ->from('UserBundle:User','User')
                        ->andWhere('User.user_roles >= :rol')
                        ->setParameter('rol', $rol)
                        ->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
        break;
    case 2:
        $entities = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('User')
            ->from('UserBundle:User','User')
            ->andWhere('User.user_roles > :rol')
            ->andWhere('User.user_organizaciones = :organizacion')
            ->orWhere('User.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('rol', $rol)
            ->setParameter('organizacion', $orgId)
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
            break;
}
return new JsonResponse($entities);
```

It's also bringing the password. I don't want to bring that data, how can I do it? Should I need to modify something in the User entity?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
 */
private $password;
```

Edit: This is what it brings:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the serializer component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: Ok. thanks. I'm learning how to do DQL's

Comment: You can do `->select('User.field, User.field2')` I think.

Comment: Lol, yup, I was going to write that, thanks, that's what I needed.